# Apache Velocity log to console for debugging

Tags: velocity, xwiki

Using Apache velocity in xwiki, how do I create a `console.log()` like one would in JavaScript? I know the log will probably be server side. I really just want to print the values of variables as it is rendered for debugging purposes.

I should add that the page I'm trying to debug is a form `.post` page, thus not rendered by its self, only returns data. Thus `{{velocity output="false"}}` mode, so simply printing the variable is not an option.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7972815  To inject the logger, maybe a groovy macro will be useful - use the XWiki `xcontext` to put the logger into and fetch it in the velocity macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since XWiki 6.1 you can use logging script service to get a standard logger:

`$services.logging.getLogger('My script').info('Hello {}', 'world')`

See http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Logging+Module#HGetaLoggerfromscript for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble to figure out what's the value for 'My Script'. Turns out the function getLogger() will take a logger_name as input parameter, where logger_name can be any of the logger name in ..WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml.
For example, this works for me:  $services.logging.getLogger('org.xwiki').info('Hello {}', 'world')